# import modulname-Swift.h is working in .m but not in .h files

Tags: objective-c, swift

I try to mix swift and Obj-c in my project.
I made a couple of Swift classes (and protocolls).
If I put #import "ModuleName-Swift.h" to an .m file, it's working properly, but if i try to put it to a .h file, it says "ModuleName-Swift.h" file not found.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

## import <ModuleName-Swift.h>

try using angle brackets instead.